# TF KERAS - ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable:

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tf.keras

Was trying to build actor critic model. Everything works fine until i call train_step method

```
import collections
import numpy as np
import statistics
import tensorflow as tf
import tqdm

from tensorflow.keras import layers
from typing import Any, List, Sequence, Tuple


class ActorCritic(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.fc1 = layers.Dense(256, activation="relu")
        self.fc2 = layers.Dense(128, activation="relu")
        self.fc3 = layers.Dense(64, activation="relu")
        self.actor = layers.Dense(13)
        self.critic = layers.Dense(1)

    def call(self, inputs: tf.Tensor) -> Tuple[tf.Tensor, tf.Tensor]:
        #x = self.fc1(inputs)
        #x = self.fc2(x)
        x = self.fc3(inputs)
        return self.actor(x), self.critic(x)


class CreepBlock:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ep = 0
        self.model = ActorCritic()
        self.eps = np.finfo(np.float32).eps.item()
        self.gamma = 0.999
        self.times = tf.range(10000)
        self.huber_loss = tf.keras.losses.Huber(reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.SUM)
        self.optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01)

    def start_episode(self):
        self.t = 0
        self.ep += 1
        self.action_probs = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.float32, size=0, dynamic_size=True)
        self.values = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.float32, size=0, dynamic_size=True)
        self.rewards = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.int32, size=0, dynamic_size=True)

    def update_pos(self, hero_pos: List, creeps_pos: List):
        self.hero_pos = [hero_pos[0], hero_pos[1]]
        self.creeps_pos = []
        for i in range(4):
            self.creeps_pos.append([creeps_pos[i][0], creeps_pos[i][1]])

        self.state = []
        for i in range(4):
            self.state.append((self.creeps_pos[i][0] - self.hero_pos[0]) / 275)
            self.state.append((self.creeps_pos[i][1] - self.hero_pos[1]) / 275)

        self.state = tf.constant(self.state, dtype=tf.float32)
        print('self.state: ', self.state)

    def calc_reward(self):
        reward = 0
        terminal = False
        t1_pos = np.array([-1544, -1408])
        for i in range(4):
            dist = np.linalg.norm(
                np.array(self.creeps_pos[i]) - np.array(self.last_creeps_pos[i])
            )
            h_dist = np.linalg.norm(
                np.array(self.hero_pos) - np.array(self.creeps_pos[i])
            )
            if h_dist < 500:
                if dist < 20:
                    reward += 5
                elif dist < 40:
                    reward += 3
                elif dist < 60:
                    reward += 2

            if (
                np.linalg.norm(np.array(self.creeps_pos[i]))
                - np.linalg.norm(np.array(self.hero_pos))
                < 0
            ):
                reward -= 10
                terminal = True

            if np.linalg.norm(np.array(self.creeps_pos[i])) + 100 < np.linalg.norm(
                t1_pos
            ):
                terminal = True

        return np.array(reward, np.int32), terminal

    def run_step(self):
        terminal = False

        # Convert state into a batched tensor (batch size = 1)
        state = tf.expand_dims(self.state, 0)

        # Run the model and to get action probabilities and critic value
        action_logits_t, value = self.model(state)

        # Sample next action from the action probability distribution
        action = tf.random.categorical(action_logits_t, 1)[0, 0]
        action_probs_t = tf.nn.softmax(action_logits_t)

        self.values = self.values.write(self.times[self.t], tf.squeeze(value))

        self.action_probs = self.action_probs.write(self.times[self.t], action_probs_t[0, action])

        if self.times[self.t] > 0:
            reward, terminal = self.calc_reward()
            self.rewards = self.rewards.write(self.times[self.t], reward)

        self.last_creeps_pos = self.creeps_pos

        self.t += 1

        return action, terminal

    def end_episode(self):
        self.action_probs = self.action_probs.stack()
        self.values = self.values.stack()
        self.rewards = self.rewards.stack()

    def get_episode_data(self):
        return self.action_probs, self.values, self.rewards

    def get_expected_return(self, 
                            rewards: tf.Tensor, 
                            standardize: bool = True):
        
        n = tf.shape(rewards)[0]
        returns = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.float32, size=n)

        rewards = tf.cast(rewards[::-1], dtype=tf.float32)
        discounted_sum = tf.constant(0.0)
        discounted_sum_shape = discounted_sum.shape
        for i in tf.range(n):
            reward = rewards[i]
            discounted_sum = reward + self.gamma * discounted_sum
            discounted_sum.set_shape(discounted_sum_shape)
            returns = returns.write(i, discounted_sum)
        returns = returns.stack()[::-1]

        if standardize:
            returns = ((returns - tf.math.reduce_mean(returns)) / 
                       (tf.math.reduce_std(returns) + self.eps))

        return returns

    

    def compute_loss(
        self, action_probs: tf.Tensor, 
        values: tf.Tensor, 
        returns: tf.Tensor):

        huber_loss = tf.keras.losses.Huber(reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.SUM)
        advantage = returns - values

        action_log_probs = tf.math.log(action_probs)
        actor_loss = -tf.math.reduce_sum(action_log_probs * advantage)

        critic_loss = huber_loss(values, returns)
        print('actor loss: ', actor_loss)
        print('critic loss: ', critic_loss)

        return actor_loss + critic_loss

    @tf.function
    def train_step(self):
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            
            action_probs, values, rewards = self.get_episode_data()

            print(action_probs, values, rewards)

            returns = self.get_expected_return(rewards)

            action_probs, values, returns = [
                tf.expand_dims(x, 1) for x in [action_probs, values, returns]]

            loss = self.compute_loss(action_probs, values, returns)
        
        grads = tape.gradient(loss, self.model.trainable_variables)
        print('loss: ', loss)
        print('grads:', grads)
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, self.model.trainable_variables))

        episode_reward = tf.math.reduce_sum(self.rewards)

        return episode_reward
```

I don't know why, but
`grads = tape.gradient(loss, self.model.trainable_variables)`
returns `['None, None, None, None, None, None]`
And then i get this:
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: (['actor_critic/dense_2/kernel:0', 'actor_critic/dense_2/bias:0', 'actor_critic/dense_3/kernel:0', 'actor_critic/dense_3/bias:0', 'actor_critic/dense_4/kernel:0', 'actor_critic/dense_4/bias:0'],). Provided `grads_and_vars` is ((None, <tf.Variable 'actor_critic/dense_2/kernel:0' shape=(8, 64) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'actor_critic/dense_2/bias:0' shape=(64,) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'actor_critic/dense_3/kernel:0' shape=(64, 13) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'actor_critic/dense_3/bias:0' shape=(13,) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'actor_critic/dense_4/kernel:0' shape=(64, 1) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'actor_critic/dense_4/bias:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32>))

Comment: try to remove the random operation from your training process and see if the error will change:   action = tf.random.categorical